# The word government in colloquial speech

Tags: usage

In colloquial speech, does the word "government" refer to the executive political force in a country (especially when capitalized,) or does it always encompass the legislative and judicial bodies as well?

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I once speculated to a well-educated young American that the UK government might fall.  The American was shocked and thought this meant that the UK was on the verge of descending into anarchy.  But actually I just meant that there might need to be an early general election.

Comment: Words rarely “always” encompass one thing. _Generally_ encompass? Sure. _Usually_ encompass? You bet. But _always_ encompass? Not very often.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely encompasses the legislative branch, and often the judicial branch too but not always.

For example if I get a parking violation I might complain that "the government is stealing my money". What I'm actually talking about here is a mixture of the legislative branch (either local or national) which creates the laws and the judicial branch which enforces them.

In other cases the judicial system is treated differently, for example, there are cases when the government acts as a prosecutor or defender in a legal case (for example, the attorney general). In these cases you could talk about "the government's opening arguments to the judge".

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial BrE (and also a lot of formal BrE, in newspapers etc), "the **government**" rarely includes the judicial branch, and often refers solely to the executive branch (and sometimes even more specifically to government ministers).

BrE often uses the expression "the government" where AmE uses "the administration" (though BrE will use the term "administration" when discussing American politics, and it is occasionally used when discussing British politics as well).

In the British Parliament (and comparable foreign parliaments) we refer to "the government benches" and "government MPs" opposed by "opposition MPs".

Oxford Living Dictionaries defines **government** as follows:

> *treated as singular or plural* The group of people with the authority to govern a country or state; a particular ministry in office

and gives examples including:

> ‘the government's economic record’
>
> ‘successive Labour governments’
>
> ‘That government and nation may commit itself to that ideology for one hundred years or more.’
>
> ‘He was to form no less than fourteen governments as Prime Minister during the rest of his life.’
>
> ‘One of the immediate tasks of a new government and the international community will be bringing war criminals to justice.’

As a secondary definition, it has:

> *mass noun* The system by which a state or community is governed

But if you look up "**government**" in Oxford's online [American](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/government) edition, the primary definition is quite different:

> *treated as singular or plural* The governing body of a nation, state, or community

Still, the more restrictive definition of "**government**" (= the executive) can also be used in AmE in some cases, but it is less common and isn't the default understanding in the way that it is in BrE.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/government) has this:

> *6* :the body of persons that constitutes the governing authority of a political unit or organization: such as
>
> *a* :the officials comprising the governing body of a political unit and constituting the organization as an active agency  *The government was slow to react to the crisis.*
>
> *b capitalized* :the executive branch of the U.S. federal government
>
> *c capitalized* :a small group of persons holding simultaneously the principal political executive offices of a nation or other political unit and being responsible for the direction and supervision of public affairs:
>
> (1) :such a group in a parliamentary system constituted by the cabinet or by the ministry  (2) :administration 4b

I agree that when capitalised, it is more likely to mean the executive (see M-W's definitions), but in BrE there is a strong tendency to a narrow understanding of "government" even when lower case.  In BrE at least it would generally be considered grossly misleading to say that the government had prohibited something if it was a judge who had done so, and we often speak of judges ruling against the government (Americans would generally say "against the administration").  We also speak (in BrE) of the government winning or losing votes in Parliament.